# Checar caracteres alphanumérico em campo

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

Estou com um problema de validação em um campo de texto. Preciso que o campo  **não permita caracteres ALPHANUMÉRICOS**, esta validação tem que ser feita **obrigatoriamente com jquery**.

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes? Pode colocar algo que você tentou fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Você não deu muitas informações sobre o jQuery Validate, apesar de ter marcado explicitamente o tópico com essa tag. Mas também você não nos forneceu nenhuma base para trabalho.

Então eu tenho de considerar as duas possibilidades.

Sem jQuery Validate

```
<input id="field" name="field" />
<button type="button" id="button">OK</button>

$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( '#button' ).click( function( e ) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if( new RegExp( "[a-zA-z0-9]+" ).test( $( '#field' ).val() ) === false ) {
            alert( 'Somente caracteres alfa-numéricos' );
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvuj3pbx/)

Com jQuery Validate:

```
<form id="form">
    <input id="field" name="field" />
    <button type="button" id="button">OK</button>
</form>

$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( '#form' ).validate({

        rules: {
            field: { pattern: /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/ }
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qupen6sg/)

Atente apenas para o detalhe de [um arquivo adicional](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js) sendo incluído no segundo Fiddle. Eu não uso a jQuery Validate então não sei se esta versão que eu usei é a mais atualizado ou não.

Veja que a técnica Expressão Regular a mesma para ambos os casos, muda apenas a implementação.

Comment: testei as duas implementações e não funcionou. @bruno-augusto

Comment: Como você testou? No primeiro Fiddle, digitando qualquer coisa alfanumérica e clicando no botão não acontece nada. Colocando algum símbolo, faz aparecer um alert(). No segundo Fiddle, digitando qualquer coisa não alfanumérica, com um simples TAB faz aparecer **Invalid format** entre a caixa de texto e o botão.

Comment: eu resolvi o meu problema com uma aplicação simples em html5 defini a regra da expressão regular com pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 .]{3,30}". Mas mesmo assim obrigado!

Comment: @IvanFloripa, sua 'solução' vai de encontro com o que você deseja: **obrigatoriamente com jquery**. A resposta do Bruno resolve seu problema, usando jquery, como você descreveu.

Comment: eu procurei outra solução pois eu testei na minha aplicação e não funcionou @papa-charlie

Comment: @IvanFloripa, mas no *fiddle* funciona, talvez seja uma questão minima de ajuste. Se você explanar o erro que ocorreu, vai ser mais fácil manter o foco no jQuery como deseja.